# How to add plugin variable in meteor cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

How to pass variable in cordova plugin??

In normal cordova

```
cordova -d plugin add /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

In meteor I tried

```
App.configurePlugin('nl.x-services.plugins.googleplus@https', {
  'APP_ID': '12345789',
  'APP_NAME': 'app_name'
});
```

But I got

```
Error while running for mobile platforms: Failed to install plugin com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect: Variable(s) missing (use: --variable APP_ID=value --variable
APP_NAME=value).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the plugin name is `com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect`, not `nl.x-services.plugins.googleplus@https`